# Loop over empty iterator does not raise exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am on Python 3.6.7.

I just noticed that a `for` loop over an empty list does not loop even once. 
After some thought, that made some sense to me. I.e. a loop over a zero-sized (empty) object returns zero iterations.

```
iterable = []
for element in iterable:
    pass
print(element)
>>> NameError: name 'element' is not defined
```

This means that a test inside the loop will not be executed if `len(iterable) == 0`.

```
iterable = []
for element in iterable:
    assert isinstance(element, int)
#nothing happens
```

Then how can I catch this situation?

Is there a compact built-in way to raise an error when my loop does not run because the iterable is empty?

Catching this particular situation requires manually:

- testing that the `iterator` is non-empty before the loop
- testing that the element was defined, after the loop. Neither
  method seems elegant to me

And I may end up having this test in every single `for` loop.

```
assert len(iterable) > 0
#loop
```

or

```
#loop
assert "element" in dir() #?
```

Comment: instead of `assert len(iterator) > 0` you can just use `assert iterator` - empty iterators are Falsey: `bool([]) == False`.

Comment: Note that iterators have neither length nor boolean sense by default. Iterables do, but they are a tiny subset of things that act as iterators.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to catch empty iterators, do you want to assert the nested type of an empty iterator, do you want an example where empty iterators are useful, do you want to raise an exception on empty loops, ...?

Comment: MisterMiyagi I have removed my consideration about use of empty iterators. This makes the question asked more clear (`Is there a compact built-in way to raise an error when my loop does not run because the iterable is empty?`)

Comment: MisterMyagi I edited and replaced `iterator` with `iterable`

Comment: But you already have that - if the loop didn't run at all, you get a `NameError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no builtin way to directly check for empty iterators. Empty iterators are generally not considered exceptional. However, you can define compact helpers to explicitly check for empty iterators.

---

Detecting empty iterators up-front is generally not possible. In some cases, one can guess from the source of an iterator whether it is empty -- for example, iterators of sequences and mappings are empty if their parent is boolean false. However, iterators themselves do not have any indication for content and may in fact be "empty" unless iterated over.

The only reliable means is to check whether an iterator provides items *while iterating*.
One can define a wrapper iterator that raises an error if an iterator provides no items at all.

```
def non_empty(iterable):
    """Helper to ensure that ``iterable`` is not empty during iteration"""
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    try:
        yield next(iterator)  # explicitly check first item
    except StopIteration:
        raise LookupError(f'{iterable} is empty') from None
    yield from iterator       # forward iteration of later items
```

Such a helper can be wrapped around both iterables and iterators, and works in `for` loops, explicit `iter` iterators and any other iteration scenario.

```
>>> iterable = []
>>> for element in non_empty(iterable):
...    assert isinstance(element, int)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in non_empty
LookupError: [] is empty
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Statements, and else Clauses on Loops](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

> Loop statements may have an `else` clause; it is executed when the loop **terminates through exhaustion** of the iterable.

For example:

```
iterator = []
for element in iterator:
    print('This wont print..')
else:
    assert iterator
```

This will results with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 4, in <module>
    assert iterator
AssertionError
```

Comment: The `else` has no meaning here. It is only relevant when you actually `break` the loop. Here, it would be exactly the same like simply writing the `assert` right after the loop

Comment: The `else` take effect only when the `loop` **exhausts**, `break` will case the `loop` to stop its iterations, therefore the `else` will *not* happen.

Comment: Exactly my point. There is no `break` here -> so the loop **always** exhausts -> so the `else` has no effect...

Comment: I am unaccepting this answer because the comment of Tomerikoo is correct: the `else` at the end will execute whether `iterable` is empty or not

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to do something if the loop wont run because the list is empty? It's perfectly normal behavior. If you expect for some reason to have at least one item (maybe having no items in array is a measure of error in your program) then check if `len(iterator) == 0` as you suggested earlier. Its a perfectly valid way to do it.

By the way exeptions are the way to go in those cases when you are checking the values of variables etc. Asserts are more of the hard-coded info for critical failures and SHOULD NOT be used for reporting usual errors as they cant be handled.

Comment: Context to my question: I usually capture a list of files available in a folder that match a pattern. For example, `[f for f in os.listdir() if f.endswith('.tar')]`, and then iterate over those. If I have no files, no matter the exceptions raised inside the loop, the loop will not be executed and I miss what really happened.

Comment: @AndreaMassetti I think checking things before iteration is the way to go, since if loop does not run then you cant check anything in it. If checking your variables or lists is too cumbersome with oneliners and/or requires multiple statements then i would consider isolating logic into a function. As far as i know this is the most pytonic way. Good luck.