# How to log that an iterator yielded n or zero times?

Tags: python

I want to log the number of things in an iterator (not trying to catch an empty iterator, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60056208/2071807)), after I've iterated over it and done something else for each thing.

My instinct here is to use the `enumerate` built-in:

```py
def foo_yielder():
     to_yield = ['foo', 'bar']
     for x in to_yield:
         yield x

for i, x in enumerate(foo_yielder(), start=1):
    print(x)

# Now log how many things we printed
print(f"We logged {i} things")
```

But if the iterator has nothing to yield, `i` never gets defined.

If this were Javascript I'd do:

```js
`We logged ${i || 0} things`
```

Taking lessons from C, we could do:

```
i = 0
for x in foo_yielder():
    print(x)
    i = i + 1
print("We logged " + i + " things.")
```

But that seems incredibly lame somehow.

Is there an elegant thing I could do here?

Comment: My particular use case has to do with iterating over database cursor results, and what to do if the query returned no results.

Comment: Why not put `i = 0` before the loop, then if the loop doesn't clobber `i`, you'll output 0?

Comment: The other option would be to set this up with an if/else statement, but just defining ```i``` is probably still the best option.

Comment: You could also use an `else` statement in the `for` loop

Comment: @LondonRob which package do you use to access your db?

Comment: @Gabip I wanted to keep this question generic. Just added a use case for your stimulation and delight.

Comment: @LondonRob I asked since there are attributes for cursors indicating the current position in the result set. For example, for `psycopg` cursor, there is a `rownumber` attribute: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.rownumber

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing would be to add a `i = 0` right before the `enumerate` loop.

---

If what bothers is the `i = 0` additional line being ugly, you can try the following way:

Add a *"dummy"* iterator and [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) it to your iterator. Then, reset the `enumerate` to count from `0` (as the default). This way, you assure that the `enumerate` will iterate on at least one item (and set `i` to `0`), and then count the actual iterator from `1`:

```py
from itertools import chain

for i, x in enumerate(chain([0], foo_yielder())):
    pass
print(f"We logged {i} things")
```

This then offers another problem of `x` always being the *dummy* on the first iteration. You could handle that with conditions inside the loop, but that would make the code more complicated.

---

Lastly, you could wrap the final printing with a `try/except`:

```py
try:
    print(f"We logged {i} things")
except NameError:
    print(f"We logged 0 things")
```

But again, that is just more code, instead of a simple `i = 0`.

Answer (score -4):

Setting this up to enumerate over an empty list, the `else` clause on the for loop will always execute after the loop has finished, checking for the existence of `i` in the current namespace. The interstitial `print` statement isn't really necessary. I don't know if it's exactly elegant, but it's a nice use-case for the `for-else` idiom.

```
for i, _ in enumerate([], start=1):
    pass # do whatever you want here
else:
    if "i" in dir():
        print(f"Found {i} instances")
    else:
        print(f"Found instances")
```

This does, of course, presume that you haven't used `i` as a variable elsewhere

And of course, slightly cleaner (DRY, and all that)

```
for i, _ in enumerate([], start=1):
    pass # do whatever you want here
else:
    if "i" not in dir():
        i = 0
print(f"We logged {i} things")
```

Comment: What is the benefit of the else clause here? It would do the same if you remove the else completely.

Comment: I like that it explicitly ties the behaviour into the loop, so that if changes are made in future, it's easier to see everything that's in scope

Comment: `else` is only semantically useful if you `break` somewhere. https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Comment: I think I prefer your answer in the comments @Andrew to set `i = 0` then use enumerate.